# Not able to add ScrollView to StackLayout Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i have a stacklayout which has a scrollview, but when i add the scrollview to this stacklayout, the stacklayout aligns completely towards the left and the scroll automatically scrolls up and the layout is draggable for some reason. please help.

```py
class Notice(Screen):
    layout = StackLayout(size_hint=(0.8,0.8),pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.4},orientation='lr-tb',spacing=20)
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(self.width, self.height))
        root.add_widget(self.layout)

        notices = os.listdir('Notices')
        no_of_notices = len(notices)
        

        for i in range(0,no_of_notices):
            print(f"i value = {i}")
            file = str(notices[i])
            
            card = MDCard(
            style= 'elevated',
            size_hint= (1,0.2)
            )
            
            with open(f'Notices/{file}','r') as f:
                data = f.read()
                notice=Label(text=data)

            self.layout.add_widget(card) 
            card.add_widget(notice)

        

        self.add_widget(root)

        return super().on_enter(*args)
```

how it looks: [Click here to see the video](https://youtu.be/p6skkfR9ZAc)

how it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.